# Check for the entered email

Tags: javascript, regex

Studying regexp in javascript. I need to make check for the entered email.

Have this:

```
reg=/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/
```

But I need to check if this email ends on `@google.com` or `@me.com`. Like `/@google.com$|@me.com$/`. Almost break my mind. Help me please)

Comment: Take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/8298495

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a programming point of view, you should just start by checking if your email string [terminates](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_endswith.asp) with `@google.com` or `@me.com` and only then run your regexp.

This will save you time: the regexp will be the all generic mail-format regexp you know and you can add more domains filters at any other time (put the terminating domains in an array or config...).

It also is a lot less CPU intensive. If you need to perform those checks in series and expect a lot of emails to be filtered out, then you will note an appreciable difference: dummy string comparisons are way faster than regexps.

---

```js
var emails = ['jose@me.com', 'hacker@noway.com', 'hacker";DROP TABLES;@me.com' ];
var domains = ['gmail.com', 'me.com'];

function validateEmailFormat(email) {
    return /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email)
}

function validateEmailDomain(email) {
    for (i in domains) {
 if (email.endsWith('@'+domains[i])) {
     return true;
 }
    }
    return false;
}

for (i in emails) {
    email = emails[i];
    if (validateEmailDomain(email) && validateEmailFormat(email)) {
 console.log('OK for '+email);
    } else {
 console.log('NOT OK for '+email);
    }
}
```

Comment: so it will be better to do like this `return /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})$/.test(string) && /@outlook\.com$|@me\.com$/.test(string)`?

Comment: Updated to include code example that you can use with the `Run code snippet` feature.

Comment: amazing, I understood. Thank you very much!

Comment: Re-updated to shorten the code now you got it you can manipulate it easy. Enjoy ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Validating e-mail addresses with a regular expression is a tricky thing. I guess if you only want to allow certain domains it simplifies things a bit. Something like could do the trick:

```
\w+@(google|me)\.com$
```

The `\w+` before the `@` is of course over simplified. Expand this to what you need ...